# Importing/Loading large XML files into Oracle

Tags: sql, xml, oracle, load

I am having problem with loading very big XML file into Oracle DB (80MB). XML file looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<names>
<catalog>
<row>
<col name="NAME">John</col>
<col name="SURNAME">Smith</col>
<col name="AGE">24</col>
</row>
<row>
<col name="NAME">Matt</col>
<col name="SURNAME">Lick</col>
<col name="AGE">14</col>
</row>
</catalog>
</names>
```

Code that I am trying to make it work looks like this:

```
CREATE directory TEST_DIR  AS 'c:\Test';

INSERT INTO NAMES(NAME,SURNAME,AGE)
WITH t AS (SELECT xmltype(bfilename('TEST_DIR','NAMES.xml'), nls_charset_id('UTF8'))     xmlcol FROM dual)
SELECT extractValue(value(x),'/row/col[@name="NAME"]') NAME         
,extractValue(value(x),'/row/col[@name="SURNAME"]') SURNAME  
,extractValue(value(x),'/row/col[@name="AGE"]') AGE

FROM t,TABLE(XMLSequence(extract(t.xmlcol,'/names/catalog/row'))) x;
```

What I get is infinite loop (I waited 4h for request for end.) When I tried with a bit smaller file like 40MB it worked - I got info that 160 000 records were inserted in 253s.
Is there any parameter or something that can make this import work as well for bigger files ?? I am doing something wrong ?

cheers

Answer (score 0):

The XML is parsed on DOM (Document Object Model) method, when you use functions like `extractValue` or `xmltype`. This creates a big overhead in memory, once I read something about factor 10-20! In general it's not smart to parse XML documents with a DOM parser if they are bigger than let's say "upper range of two digits MB".

For big documents you have to use a stream based parser, typically a SAX parser. In most cases the coding is more, however the structure of you document is very simple, so it should be no problem.

In my application I have to load XML Files of up to 1 GB into my Oracle DB, I wrote the parser in  Perl using [XML::Twig](http://search.cpan.org/~mirod/XML-Twig-3.44/Twig.pm), it works very well.

Comment: Thanks for your help! I wrote some STAX java parser, and it works very fast and smooth! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

store as a securefile binary xml so you get the optimization it provides.

```
CREATE TABLE xxx ( xml_file XMLTYPE ) XMLTYPE xml_file STORE as securefile binary xml;

INSERT INTO xxx ( xml_file ) 
( SELECT XMLTYPE(bfinename(<directory object>,<file name>, nls_charset_id(<character set>)) from dual );
```

here i'd suggest changing <col name="???"> to <???></???> in the xml to make your life easier.

```
SELECT name, surname, age
FROM XMLTABLE('/names/catalog/row' passing (SELECT xml_file FROM xxx) 
               COLUMNS name VARCHAR2(4000),
                       surname VARCHAR2(4000),
                       age NUMBER);
```